# How to add Add Search Index view mode in eck entity type?

Tags: 8

I am using ECk module in one of my content for displaying content in managed way .
The problem which i am facing the content in eck fields not creating search index when we are searching its content by input any string in search block nothing is searching regarding that field.

I have properly indexed all the node in admin/config/search/pages

Actually when i am enabling **search index view mode** in any content type then its content is searchable otherwise not.
There is no option to add **search index view mode** in Eck entity type like node content type.

I want to programatically add **search index view mode** in ECK field.

I want to do something like below code

```
$entity_type="eck"; //The entity for which you want to create the view mode
$view_mode="search index"; //The name of the new view mode
$settings=Array();
$settings["id"]=$entity_type.".".$view_mode;
$settings["targetEntityType"]=$entity_type;
$evm=Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewMode::create($settings);
$evm->save();
```

Comment: Have you tried using https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api module which supports all entities?

Comment: Actually i am creating drupal 8 based site which is having only 4 pages ,to implement search_api its a bulky process on clients server,thats why i am looking for some alternative solution.

Comment: You don't need a special view mode for the ECK entity (it wouldn't help much, because ECK has no search plugin). Since you only want to index the ECK entity when referenced from a content type, not on its own, you can display the reference field as rendered entity with the default view mode.

Comment: can you elaborate more in answer i am in great need of help?

Comment: You ask specifically for a ECK view mode and how to create it programmatically. My comment is not to answer, but to clarify if you need to do this.

Comment: Check https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/229681/67770

Comment: @IsmailCherri, it's still unclear what the OP wants to achieve. In the title it's about indexing ECK entities, in the question it's twice mentioned it is about a ECK field, which is probably a reference field to a ECK entity in a content type. We have to wait until this is clarified before we can make suggestions.